# Existe forma de esconder um url em uma página web?

Tags: php, html, url

Vamos por partes, estou a fazer um site onde vou ler um URL da base de dados e a seguir vou usá-lo em uma imagem, ao clicar nela(imagem) vai abrir esse URL (dentro de um iframe ou em um novo separador).

No código, tenho uma página usando *HTML* e *PHP* onde mostro a imagem com o URL da hiperligação **visível**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    <?php
        include ("connection.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div class=\"gallery\">";
                echo "  <a target=\"iframe1\" href=\"".$row["url"]."\" onclick=\"openiframe()\">";
                echo "    <img src=\"images\\".$row["image"]."\" width=\"600\" height=\"400\">";
                echo "  </a>";
                echo "  <div class=\"desc\"><a href=\"".$row["url"]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$row["name"]."</a></div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        $conn->close();
    ?> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O resultado do código anterior é algo como isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo bem, agora o que eu pretendia era não ser **visível** o URL, na imagem seguinte assinalei o que falo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe forma de ocultar o URL usando por exemplo *PHP* ou alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antigamente, muito antigamente, existia um método para isso: `window.status`. Bastava você colocar no link algo como `onmouseover="window.status='Olá'"` que ao passar o mouse sobre o link aparecia "*Olá*" na barra de status do navegador em vez do link no `href`.

Porém, esse método foi abolido e não tem mais suporte nos navegadores mais modernos.

Uma solução é usar o método `window.open` com `onclick` abrindo a URL numa nova aba (alguns navegadores irão abrir em nova janela):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='window.open("destino.html","_blank")'>link</a>
```

Desta forma irá aparecer "**javascript:void(0)**' no navegador em vez da URL, e a URL "destino.html" será aberta em uma nova aba/janela ("_blank").

**Usando uma função e excluindo o script nas "opções de programador" (developers tools):**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='abrirURL("qualquercoisa")'>link</a>
```

ou

```
<a href="javascript:abrirURL('qualquercoisa')">link</a>
```

Script com um `id`:

```
<script id="novaJanela">
function abrirURL(i){
    if(i == "qualquercoisa"){
        i = "destino.html";
    }
    window.open(i,i);
}

// aqui eu excluo virtualmente a tag script da página pelo id "novaJanela"
// não há problema em excluir essa tag, ela continuará funcionando
// porque já foi inserida na memória após o carregamento da página
window.onload = document.getElementById("novaJanela").outerHTML = '';
</script>
```

Comment: fiz uma edição na pergunta pois não se notava muito bem a outra seta, além disso preciso também de esconder no "código" o URL

Comment: @Tmc Atualizei a resposta mudando o href de "#" para "javascript:void(0)"

Comment: resultou o que da forma que fala para mudar não aparecer o URL ao fundo da página no entanto falta nas "opções de programador" veja na imagem da pergunta o que falo se não me perceber. Tenho duas setas na imagem.

Comment: @Tmc Entendi, vc quer ocultar nos dois lugares?

Comment: exatamente, precisava disso, existe forma?

Comment: @Tmc Existe criando uma função e atribuindo uma variável para a URL. Porém se o usuário visualizar o código fonte poderá ver a URL na função, mas é possível excluir a função nas "opções de programador".

Comment: @Tmc Acrescentei na resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67363/discussion-between-tmc-and-dvd).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `file_get_contents`, e nela passar a `URL` da sua imagem. A função irá retornar um `base64` da sua imagem, então é só você colocar esse `base64` dentro da `tag` `IMG`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$base64 = file_get_contents('caminho_da_sua_imagem');
echo "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64, ".$base64."\">";
```

Lembre-se que para cada extensão, é necessário informar no `SRC`:

- PNG = `<img src="data:image/png;base64, seu_base64">`
- JPG = `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, seu_base64">`
- GIF = `<img src="data:image/gif;base64, seu_base64">`

Comment: eu não queria escoder o URL da imagem mas sim o URL da hiperligação da imagem como, está identificado na imagem que postei

Comment: isso também pode ser usado para um URL?